# Noindex, follow all list pages

Tags: meta, list-view

I am trying to get a No-index,follow on all List Mode pages. 
To index all grid pages is just fine, but i do not want all duplicated list pages to be in the search result. been playing around but not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add noindex,follow to list view you need to open
`app/design/frontend/default/%templatename%/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`
directory

Find `$this->getMode()!='grid')`  there
You will need to wrap this code with noindex,follow tags.

Note that default Magento page Index will be there, and I'm not sure what crawlers decide as main tag.

You can play around with googleoff tags like 
 Code you need to block from Google 
This way you will be able to block the exact section of the page from being indexed.

Though I'd recommend to block the list mode not to get duplicated content or meta data (missing, short, long or duplicated meta names, descriptions).

You can block list mode in robots file
Disallow:   *?mode=list
I guess you know this option, but the best solution (I use it on my store and it helps me to get rid of duplicated content errors) is to use Google Crowl Parameters in Google Webmaster Tools. Open WMT, go to

> WMT -> Crawl -> URL Parameters

add all parameters here. Google knows better what to do with those things. Today Google wants to follow them, tomorrow Google will change its mind and will consider this option as a cheat and try to increase number of pages on your store and you will have penalty. There's no need to argue with Google :)

[image: That's how I do and forgot about problems with all parameters I use on my store]

Hope it helps you to change your mind and use tools that Google offers.